# Export to excel file when use MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Now i'm want to export data to excel,and i follow step in this
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;192348
but in step 9 when i add new class in MS visual 2010 it's only have "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library" and it have many interface to generate a new class.I don't know choose what interface,because i can't find excel8 or same that.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Article ID: 192348 - Last Review: April 11, 2007 - Revision: 5.2
APPLIES TO

```
Microsoft Office Excel 2007
Microsoft Office Excel 2003
Microsoft Excel 2002 Standard Edition
Microsoft Excel 2000 Standard Edition
Microsoft Excel 97 Standard Edition
Microsoft Visual C++ 5.0 Enterprise Edition
Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 Enterprise Edition
Microsoft Visual C++ 5.0 Professional Edition
Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 Professional Edition
Microsoft Visual C++, 32-bit Learning Edition 6.0
Microsoft Office XP Developer Edition
Microsoft Office 2000 Developer Edition
Microsoft Foundation Class Library 4.2
```

Is your platform or IDE among any of such property for compatibility ? If not, excel8 sure isn't found.

Comment: Compatibility. your Office and your VS must be among them for you to find excel8. Later versions may have wrapped them up in some interfaces. I am not working with Office COMs, I don't know which one will do what you want.

Comment: thanks u.I dicide use 14.0 Object Library and i add all interface althought maybe something isn't use.